# I can't convert my Master-Detail field to a Lookup field because the Change Field Type button is not visible

Tags: master-detail, convert, lookup-field

[image]

I have deleted all Roll-up Summary fields in the Master object including those in the Deleted Fields but the **Change Field Type** button is still not showing. Do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @kurunve, I have updated to attach the photo. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

FOUND THE ANSWER! It was because of an active Workflow Rule that was updating the master record. The field update MUST BE DELETED and NOT JUST DEACTIVATED. The Change Field Type button now appeared.